# Xamarin Forms - use TranslateTo to slide StackLayouts up

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a page with 4 StackLayouts, OnAppearing I 'slide' the bottom 3 up so that the 2nd top one in under the top, to create a drop-down effect with a toolbar for the user to click (iconStack in the XAML), which then either slides the stack up or down.

This works fine when I click on it to slide it up and down, but when I do the slide up OnAppearing, sometimes it does not fully move up leaving some of the stack visible and I cannot see why, or see anything in debugging.

Can anyone spot anything obvious in my code?

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
           // here I get some data from the database and set labels etc before I do the next line...
            SlideUp(0);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
public void SlideUp(uint time)
        {
            TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, (headerStack.Bounds.Height - (TopLayout.Height + headerStack.Height)), time, Easing.Linear);
            headerStack.TranslateTo(0, (headerStack.Bounds.Height - (TopLayout.Height + headerStack.Height)), time, Easing.Linear);
            Articlestack.TranslateTo(0, (headerStack.Bounds.Height - (TopLayout.Height + headerStack.Height)), time, Easing.Linear);
        }

        public void SlideDown(uint time)
        {
            TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, time, Easing.Linear);
            headerStack.TranslateTo(0, 0, time, Easing.Linear);
            Articlestack.TranslateTo(0, 0, time, Easing.Linear);
        }
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="gl_mobile_app.Views.Article.ArticleInfoOpen"
             xmlns:artina="clr-namespace:UXDivers.Artina.Shared;assembly=UXDivers.Artina.Shared"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app.Views.Templates;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:ratio="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:gl_mobile_app.Controls;assembly=gl_mobile_app"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms">

  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Back" Clicked="GoBack" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
      <Grid BackgroundColor="#ede8db" x:Name="articleGrid" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="KevingroveCarouselImg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="bigImg"
                    HeightRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=200, PortraitTablet=400, LandscapeTablet=200 }" />

        <artina:Button Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="ImgZoom" Clicked="EnlargeImage" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Image="IncreaseImageIcon.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-6" Padding="30,2,30,2" x:Name="iconStack" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#ede8db" >
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.TOILET}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize ="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.WHEELCHAIR}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize ="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.CUTLERY}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.BABY}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.WIFI}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.CAMERA}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.MAP_MARKER}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
          <Label x:Name="expand"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="{x:Static ratio:FontAwesome.CHEVRON_CIRCLE_DOWN}" Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20, LandscapePhone=18, PortraitTablet=25, LandscapeTablet=20 }" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="TopLayout" Padding="30,0,30,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="#ede8db">

          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="MapMarker" Opacity="1.0">
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.MAP_MARKER}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" WidthRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20,PortraitTablet=40, LandscapeTablet=40 }" />
            <Label Text="Address" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout x:Name="AddressStack" >
            <StackLayout.Padding>
              <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <OnIdiom.Phone>
                  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="34.5,0,0,0" Android="34.5,0,0,0" />
                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="54.5,0,0,0" Android="54.5,0,0,0" />
                </OnIdiom.Tablet>
              </OnIdiom>
            </StackLayout.Padding>
            <Label x:Name="AddressLabel" >
              <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                  <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                  <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf#HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                </OnPlatform>
              </Label.FontFamily>
            </Label>
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="clock" Opacity="1.0">
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static ratio:Ingeniuus.CLOCK}" Style="{StaticResource Ingeniuus}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" WidthRequest="{artina:OnOrientationDouble PortraitPhone=20,PortraitTablet=40, LandscapeTablet=40 }"/>
            <Label Text="Opening Times" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          </StackLayout>

          <StackLayout x:Name="OpeningTimesStack">
            <StackLayout.Padding>
              <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <OnIdiom.Phone>
                  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="34.5,0,0,0" Android="34.5,0,0,0" />
                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="54.5,0,0,0" Android="54.5,0,0,0" />
                </OnIdiom.Tablet>
              </OnIdiom>
            </StackLayout.Padding>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OpeningTimesLabel" >
              <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                  <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                  <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeue-Roman.otf#HelveticaNeue-Roman" />
                </OnPlatform>
              </Label.FontFamily>
            </Label>
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout x:Name="Empty2" HeightRequest="10" />


        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" x:Name="Articlestack">
          <ListView BackgroundColor="White" Margin="-4" Parent="30,0,30,0" x:Name="ArticleListView"  CachingStrategy="RetainElement" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="6000" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemp">
                <ViewCell>
                  <local:ArticleContentItemTemplate />
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

      </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: did you try remove visibility of the stacklayout

Comment: Yes I tried that (Opacity=0), and although that hides the contents of the stack, the stack its self is still partly visible as it is a different background colour to the stack underneath.

Comment: why not set isvisible to false instead of decreasing opacity !

Comment: That did it, changing from TranslateTo to just setting the visibility looks much better, move your suggestion to an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set visibility to false but you will lose some animation of translation instead of that you can do translation and after that remove visibility this will keep it smoothly.